# Is there a serial BIOS in QEMU/KVM?

Tags: bios, qemu, linux-kvm, serial, libvirt

I'm trying to bisect a kernel issue which causes a VM not to boot.  To do that, it would be nice to get serial console output from BIOS via `virsh VM console`. (For example, GRUB can use UART0, but thats not what I am looking for.)

Question: is there a BIOS for QEMU that will print these types of notices on the serial port instead of (or in addition to) using the virtual graphics device?

From the picture below, I would like to get the text "No bootable device" from the `virsh VM console` as text over serial output, instead of the graphics card:

[image: qemu kvm not booting]

FYI, this sort of works, but its not beautiful:

```
]# virsh screenshot fw1.ewheeler.net t.jpg
]# tesseract  t.jpg stdout
Screenshot saved to t.jpg, with type of image/x-portable-pixmap
Warning:guessing pitch as xheight on row 1, block 6
iPXE (http://ipxe.urg) 99:14.9 naa9 PCIZ.10 in? run arr349a9 3FED4030 naa9

iPXE (http://ipxe.urg) 99:15.9 9339 PCIZ.10 in? run arr349a9 3FED4030 9339

iPXE (http://ipxe.urg) 99:15.9 naa9 PCIZ.10 in? run arr349a9 3FED4030 9939

Press ESC iur bunt menu.

Hunting irum Hard Disk...
Hunt failed: euuid nut read the hunt disk

Nu buutabie device.
```